# Prepare software for Ubuntu Software Center with dependency from multiverse

Tags: software-center, multiverse

We're about to publish our application to USC, but it depends on VirtualBox 4.3.x which is only available from the multiverse repo. This repo is disabled on many systems.

Is there any way to tell USC that we require that repo to be enabled so it will appropriately warn the user?

We don't really want to install VirtualBox by ourselves since it introduced a lot of headache to keep user's data safe.

**EDIT**

Actually, since our software is proprietary, won't it end up in the multiverse repo anyway? That would solve the problem by definition.